# Setting up datapath for a not-standard application (Quartus 13.0.1 on Debian 8.7.1)

Tags: debian, path

I need to setup Quartus 13.0.1 on a Debian 8.7.1 system and I followed the guide at [this wiki](http://www.armadeus.org/wiki/index.php?title=Quartus_installation_on_Linux#configure_.bashrc).

After installing I need to setup a proper path and the wiki suggests to add the following code to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export ALTERAPATH="/opt/quartus/altera/13.0sp1/"
export ALTERAOCLSDKROOT="${ALTERAPATH}/hld"
export QUARTUS_ROOTDIR=${ALTERAPATH}/quartus
export QUARTUS_ROOTDIR_OVERRIDE="$QUARTUS_ROOTDIR"
export PATH=$PATH:${ALTERAPATH}/quartus/bin
export PATH=$PATH:${ALTERAPATH}/nios2eds/bin
export PATH=$PATH:${QSYS_ROOTDIR}
```

and then just call `quartos` frim a terminal. The problem is that for some reason this doesn't work, and even if I launch the application by specifying the whole path from my terminal the program needs to call other modules from the installation directory and the system can't get there.

I noticed by using the `env` command that my path results like so:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/opt/quartus/altera/13.0sp1//quartus/bin:/opt/quartus/altera/13.0sp1//nios2eds/bin:
```

but I can't seem to get rid of the double forward slashes (I'm not sure they're normal).

How should I format my files to have a properly setup path to a modular program with a not-standard file structure?

Comment: The double slashes are due to the `ALTERAPATH` definition having a `/` at the end of it. Remove that `/`.

Comment: @thrig the double slashes were fixed (I had to restart the system), but I still can't launch without writing out the full path

Answer (score 0):

I found a method in which a different module from within the application is used and the program is now functional (as suggested by its own internal messages). Still, I'll leave the question unanswered for the problem with the path setup.